# Get input type checkbox values in one array in required format

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get values from checkboxes in the following format of an array. Maybe this is the simple problem for you guys but I am really stuck here.

**This is my input types**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="any" name="chk" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" id="any1" name="chk" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" id="any2" name="chk" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" id="any3" name="chk" value="value4">
<input type="checkbox" id="any4" name="chk" value="value5">
```

**jQuery code**

```
var fuelType =new Array();
  $.each($("input[name='chk']:checked"), function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
    fuelType.push($(this).val());
});
fuelType = fuelType.join(",");
console.log(fuelType);
```

**I am getting following log**

```
["value1,value2,value3",value4",value5"]
```

**Required response**

```
["value1","value2,"value3","value4","value5"]
```

Comment: Ok, then I'm still confused.  fuelType already fits that pattern without doing anything to it.  It's an array of strings

Comment: I don't understand why I am not getting required format, thats why I've posted here :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0y4p6w2x/  The variable is already an array of strings.  If you wanting the console log of that to print out in a pre-defined manner, then you are actually asking to take an array, format it to a string, and print the string.

Comment: Yes it is giving right output in fiddle but I don't know why I am unable to get it into my page :(

Comment: I am getting value like this ["4,electric,lpg"]0: "4,electric,lpg"length: 1

Comment: it is giving me result in 0 within all values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0y4p6w2x/1/  `[]` vs `new Array()` doesn't change the result.  You have something else going on with your code that is not reflected in your question as it currently stands.

Comment: yes I've seen that too :( code is right but not getting required result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to change you jQuery to:

```
var fuelType =new Array();
$.each($("input[name='chk']:checked"), function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
    fuelType.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(fuelType);
```

What you were doing is joining the array of strings and delimiting them with a ','. That does not create an array of strings. That creates a single string that separate the keys with ','. If you had a different set of data you could use Array.prototype.map() to create a new array, but you already have it as another poster has mentioned.

Comment: Yes you are right I was making mistake with join(); Thanks Alek and Talpar